# How to make API by using Flask Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to make a API for my SVM model to predict the data through API.

I have tried below code but getting the error while running `http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict/` URL.

Error:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019 11:36:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
NameError: name 'svmModel' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019 11:36:32] "GET /predict HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have some addresses and what to predict city ID through my model. My Model is working fine.

**Updated Error:**

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1

D:\Conda\Conda_install\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3275: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

**Edit 1**

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict?property_address=<address>` I am getting only one address output but I want to post all address prediction on Browser.

for Example:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET'])
def predict():
    property_address = request.args.get('property_address')
    print (property_address)
    # Get values from browser
    input_data = "SELECT Detail_ID,PROPERTY_ADD + ', ' + MAIN_LOCALITY + ', ' + CITY AS PROPERTY_ADDRESS FROM NHB.DBO.HFC_UNPROCESS_01JUL2018TO30SEP2018 WHERE PROPERTY_ADD is not null"
    df = pd.read_sql(input_data,cnxn)  
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)  
    df.fillna({'PROPERTY_ADDRESS': 'NA'}, inplace=True)
    test_data = df['PROPERTY_ADDRESS'].values.tolist()

    for i in range(0, 5):
            #print (test_data[i])
        class_prediced = svmModel.predict(test_data)[0] 
        output = "Predicted City ID: " + str(class_prediced)
        #print (output)
        return (output)
```

Here, I used for loop to get multiple outputs.

Inputs:

```
['Cabin K-1, Laxmi Rd, Aarey Colony, Goregaon East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400065, India',
'Aarey Colony, Goregaon East, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India',
'Goregaon East, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India']`
```

Expected Output:

On Browser:

```
'Cabin K-1, Laxmi Rd, Aarey Colony, Goregaon East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400065, India'
Predicted City ID: 1

'Aarey Colony, Goregaon East, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India'
Predicted City ID: 1

'Goregaon East, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India'
Predicted City ID: 1
```

Please suggest

Comment: I think you've accidentally pasted the question again instead of the error message

Comment: Change it to this `@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET'])`

Comment: @P.hunter the `@app.route()` by default just listens for ``GET``

Comment: You should not use the `global` keyword in Python and especially not in web frameworks like Flask. In your case it does not even make any sense to globalize the open and later closed file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are expecting `property_address` as request argument,

```
property_address = request.args.get('property_address')
```

Requesting this as a URL will probably save you from the error :

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict?property_address=<address>
```

Your custom `property_address` to get your desired output.

Comment: getting error: `NameError: name 'svmModel' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019 11:40:34] "GET /predict?property_address=%3Caddress%3E HTTP/1.1" 500 -`

Comment: @user10600066 what is your expected value in `property_address`? this must be some value, other than the default `<address>` because this is just a template value. It can be `http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict?property_address=123` or `http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict?property_address=345` etc

Comment: Request the URL with your desired value as property address

Comment: `property address` I am fetching from sql server, so there are multiple addresses

Comment: Can you please suggest? How to get multiple input from server and post on browser? as I have many addresses and want to so all addresses prediction on browser.

Comment: could you please clarify more about your problem?

Comment: Can you please suggest?

Comment: Do you want the above mentioned response in browser.?

Comment: append your response `output = "Predicted City ID: " + str(class_prediced)` inside a list and return response from your flask endpoint only after the for loop is completed

Comment: Yes, I did this process but unable to return the list but Now I am able to return all values by using this: `class_prediced = svmModel.predict(test_data)`

Comment: I need one more help from you, I am developing API for my model which will use for prediction. I am new and learning for the same but not getting any useful idea. -- API can take multi user input and predict the data accordiglly. 

For Example: User 1 and user 2 is accessing my api at same time and they given input 'someting from user 1' and 'something from user 2' 
after the data submission from web data will stored in server and then I need to call data for prediction.

How I can manage this problem? Please suggest

Comment: use flask `session` for user specific data see [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.session)

Answer (score 0):

You've used `svmModel` instead of `svmIrisModel`, which is the global variable, in this line

`class_prediced = svmModel.predict(test_data)[0]`

Comment: yes, it was type error but still getting error on browser: `Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.` and in spyder console: `NameError: name 'svmModel' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019 11:45:13] "GET /predict?property_address=%3Caddress%3E HTTP/1.1" 500 -`

Comment: @user10600066 Just post the server side error for easier debugging

Comment: @user10600066 Your new code doesn't make sense as you've just changed the global variable name. The data is loaded into a variable inaccessible by the predict function.